# How to format description label with a command (enumitem)

Tags: enumitem, verbatim, description

I have to make list environment based on description that should be used to describe `C` functions.

For example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minted}

\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m}{\texttt{#1}}

\newlist{funcDescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[funcDescription, 1]{style=nextline, font=\mdseries\ttfamily, align=left}

\begin{document}

    \begin{funcDescription}
        \item[int printf(const char * format, ...)]
            Writes the \code{C} string pointed by format to the standard output
            (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences
            beginning with \code{\%}), the additional arguments following
            format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing
            their respective specifiers.
    \end{funcDescription}
    
\end{document}
```

It produces the

[image]

But I want to apply `\mintinline` command to the `\item[]` argument. Also, I would like to pass verb text to the `\item[]` and `\code{}` argument.

So there is the questions:

1. How to apply some command to `funcDescription` items from the `\setlist`?
2. How to pass verb text to the `\code{}` command in latex with `\NewDocumentCommand{}{}{}`?
3. How to pass verb text to the argument of `\item[]`?

(`texdoc` research didn't help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses `\funcitem` instead of `\item`, which doesn't seem too big a nuisance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[code]{C}{}

\newlist{funcDescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[funcDescription, 1]{
  style=nextline,
  font=\mdseries\ttfamily,
  align=left,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcitem}{v}{\item[\code|#1|]}

\begin{document}

\begin{funcDescription}
  \funcitem{int printf(const char * format, ...)}
    Writes the \code{C} string pointed by format to the standard output
    (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences
    beginning with \code|%|), the additional arguments following
    format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing
    their respective specifiers.
  \funcitem|printf(%d,argument_list)|
    This is just to show how to do with \code|%|
\end{funcDescription}
    
\end{document}
```

In case of need, also the argument to `\funcitem` can be enclosed in `|...|` (or any other pair of equal characters, as usual for `\verb`) as shown in the example. The same for `\code`.

[image]

Comment: Dang. This is that easy. Actually, about `\funcitem`, I thought there is some LaTeX way to do so, but if expert says that  wrapper command is good enough I will take it. Thank You!